# How to quickly switch to n.10+ windows in tmux?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, tmux

Tmux by default comes with the following keybinding to quickly switch between windows numbered 0 to 9:

```
C-b + 0-9
```

With a couple of dozen different project folders, a few ssh sessions and other goodies in my tmux, I seem to always spill over the 10 windows I can quickly access, and I would love to figure out a quick way to switch to windows numbered 10 or higher. Right now I have to manually type out something along these lines in the tmux prompt:

```
swap-window -t 12
```

Which is quite time-consuming.

Has anyone figured out a solid shortcut that helps you quickly access windows 10 and higher? I know weechat solved this problem with the two shorcuts:

```
Alt + 0-9
Alt+j followed by \d{2}
```

Can anything along those lines be accomplished with tmux?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25335730/how-do-i-jump-to-double-digit-window-number-in-tmux

Answer (score 152, accepted):

There are a few easy ways to do it.

- Use `C-b '` to select the window index.
- Use `C-b w` to get an interactive index to choose from (0-9a-z).
- Add bindings to cycle through quickly in tmux.conf

  `bind -r C-h select-window -t :-`
  `bind -r C-l select-window -t :+`

The `-r` in the last one lets you repeat the key without having to repeat `C-b`.  Typically the second one is the least number of keystrokes.

Comment: The first two commands are exactly what I was looking for, thank you Jason!

Comment: Ah. I've fatfingered `C-b w` a bunch accidentally and have been spooked. Now I finally know what it's for.

Comment: Would be great if the ```C-b '``` still showed the window index on the line above instead of covering it up when it asked for ```index ```..

Answer (score 7):

You can use `switch-client -T<keytablename>` to configure a sequence of keys to directly access high-number windows.

For example I use this configuration to jump to windows 10-19 with `Ctrl-b` + `-` + `[0-9]`:

```
bind - switch-client -Tabove9
bind -Tabove9 0 select-window -t:10
bind -Tabove9 1 select-window -t:11
bind -Tabove9 2 select-window -t:12
bind -Tabove9 3 select-window -t:13
bind -Tabove9 4 select-window -t:14
bind -Tabove9 5 select-window -t:15
bind -Tabove9 6 select-window -t:16
bind -Tabove9 7 select-window -t:17
bind -Tabove9 8 select-window -t:18
bind -Tabove9 9 select-window -t:19
```

**Detailed explanation:**

As explained in the tmux manpage, `switch-client` can be used to set the current key table to create key combinations:

> switch-client [-ElnprZ] [-c target-client] [-t target-session] [-T key-table]
>
> ...
>
> -T sets the client's key table; the next key from the client will be interpreted from key-table.  This may be used to configure multiple prefix keys, or to bind commands to sequences of keys.  For example,
> to make typing ‘abc’ run the list-keys command:
>
> ```
>                bind-key -Ttable2 c list-keys
>                bind-key -Ttable1 b switch-client -Ttable2
>                bind-key -Troot   a switch-client -Ttable1
> ```

So in my example I configured the `-` key to switch to a custom table named `above9` and then configured keys `0` to `9` in that table to switch to windows `10` to `19`.

This is equivalent to GNU screen's `bind -c <class>` (that's where I come from)

Comment: Love it.  Did something like it just now, but using "+" instead of "-" and I also switched numbering to start from 1 (base-index FTW :D).  So, 1-0 do 1 to 10, and 11 to 20 are <prefix> + 1 to 0.  (And 21 to 30 are prefix + +  1-10 :D)